# Calculate the convex conjugate of f(x)?

Tags: convex-optimization, subgradient

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
-\frac{5}{2} + 2 |x| & |x|>0\\ 
-|\frac{x}{2}| & |x|\le0
\end{cases}.$$

How to calculate the conjugate gradient?

I found out that I can rewrite it to $max(-\frac{5}{2} + 2 |x|, -|\frac{x}{2}|)$...

I have found related examples: http://www.onmyphd.com/?p=legendre.fenchel.transform

Comment: Are you asking for the _conjugate function_ $f^*(\cdot)$? I think you're getting your terminology mixed up in the title.

Comment: yes conjugate function f*()